# Why won't the New York Times "skimmer" web site run in Fluid?

Tags: websites

[Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) is an application that enables a single web site, normally viewed through a web browser, to be displayed in Mac OS X as an application.

I want to have `http://nytimes.com/skimmer` in a separate process, but it won't run properly in Fluid. It has a few of the links on the bottom right, but the page stays blank.

[Information about Times Skimmer](http://www.nytimes.com/content/help/extras/skimmer/skimmer.html).

> Times Skimmer is a browser-based application that offers a new way to read The Times online. The application provides the experience of spreading out a newspaper and paging through it.

[More information](http://beta620.nytimes.com/projects/times-skimmer/). It's entirely HTML5-based, and the New York Times considers it to be an "experimental beta" project.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Fluid doesn't seem to work with that site (either to do with the HTML5 or the caching). However, Prism (http://prism.mozillalabs.com/started/) works the same way as Fluid (separate process, dock icon, etc.), and presents the content perfectly. It doesn't have many features, such as User Agents, Preferences, or Themes, but for something like Skimmer it looks great!
Hope this helps you,
Charlie